# Como fazer uma SQL fazer a contagem correta de imóveis sob certos critérios

Tags: php, sql, select, join

Tenho a seguinte SQL que faz corretamente a contagem do número de imóveis:

```
select
clientes.id,
clientes.nome, 
clientes.status,
clientes.cliente,
clientes.tipo,
clientes.disponibilidade,
imoveis.id,
imoveis.cod,
imoveis.status,
imoveis.vvenda, 
COUNT(imoveis.id) AS imoveis
from clientes
inner join imoveis on clientes.cliente = imoveis.cod 
where 
imoveis.status='2'
AND clientes.status='2' 
AND imoveis.vvenda < clientes.disponibilidade
AND imoveis.vvenda <> '0'
AND clientes.cliente = '$cliente'
AND imoveis.cod = '$cliente'
GROUP BY clientes.id
```

Só que precisei fazer uma pequena implementação (destaquei abaixo o que acrescentei) só que o número de imóveis agora está incorreto na contagem. Veja abaixo a SQL com as implementações:

```
select
clientes.id,
clientes.nome, 
clientes.status,
clientes.cliente,
clientes.tipo,
clientes.disponibilidade,
imoveis.id,
imoveis.cod,
imoveis.status,
imoveis.vvenda, 
COUNT(imoveis.id) AS imoveis,
```

> fotos.cod

```
from clientes
inner join imoveis on clientes.cliente = imoveis.cod
```

> inner join fotos on fotos.cod=imoveis.id

```
where 
imoveis.status='2'
AND clientes.status='2' 
AND imoveis.vvenda < clientes.disponibilidade
AND imoveis.vvenda <> '0'
AND clientes.cliente = '$cliente'
AND imoveis.cod = '$cliente'
GROUP BY clientes.id
```

Bastou estas simples implementações para a contagem dos imóveis ser totalmente diferente.

Preciso muito de ajuda!

Comment: O valor é diferente como? Maior ou menor que o valor "correto", qual é a relacação entre foto e imoveis? 1 pra 1, 1 pra N?

Comment: Qual é o critério que o pessoal está utilizando para negativar? A pessoa que negativou poderia informar os seus motivos aqui?

Comment: @Rubico O valor é diferente na quantidade de imóveis filtrados. No primeiro exemplo o COUNT(imoveis.id) AS imoveis exibe perfeitamente o número de imóveis. No segundo exemplo, apenas porque fiz as pequenas implentações o COUNT(imoveis.id) AS imoveis exibe valores totalmente diferente, ou seja, incorretos.

Comment: sem um conhecimento do seu banco é um pouco dificil, mas eu percebi que você está comparando o `foto.cod` com o `imovel.id`, não seria com o `imovel.cod`? Tenta mostrar qual é a estrutura do seu banco, quais são as relações.

Comment: O que o colega valou agora é válido. Como existe uma relação entre imóveis de fotos (onde um imóvel pode possuir diversas fotos), é necessário que, na tabela das fotos, exista uma coluna para guardar qual o imóvel é o "dono" da foto, ou seja, na tabela de fotos deve existir uma coluna `fotos.imovel_cod`, por exemplo, e deve ser através dessa coluna que o `inner join` seja feito ( `INNER JOIN fotos ON fotos.imovel_cod = imovel.cod` ).

Como está a estrutura da tabela fotos? Existe essa coluna para fazer a relação entre fotos e imóveis?

Answer (score 0):

Quando você faz

```
inner join fotos on fotos.cod=imoveis.id
```

você diz que para cada imoveis.id há uma foto com fotos.cod correspondente. Se sua tabela de fotos não tiver uma foto para cada imovel, o número de linhas na query com inner join vai ser menor.

Se você quiser trazer imoveis com ou sem fotos, sua nova junção deveria ser um outer join.

```
left outer join fotos on fotos.cod=imoveis.id
```