# Como saber o total de imóveis e o total de fotos em uma SQL com dois INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, join

Tenho a seguinte **SQL INNER JOIN** e gostaria de saber como posso obter o **total** de IMÓVEIS e também o total de **FOTOS**, sendo que já utilizei **COUNT(imoveis.id) AS TOTAL** para saber o total de imóveis mas o resultado não bate com a realidade:

```
select
clientes.id,
clientes.nome, 
clientes.status,
clientes.cliente,
clientes.tipo,
clientes.disponibilidade,
imoveis.id,
imoveis.cod,
imoveis.status,
imoveis.vvenda, 
fotos.cod
from clientes
inner join imoveis on clientes.cliente = imoveis.cod
inner join fotos on fotos.cod = imoveis.id
where
imoveis.status='2'
AND clientes.status='2' 
AND imoveis.vvenda < clientes.disponibilidade
AND imoveis.vvenda <> '0'
AND clientes.cliente = '$cliente'
AND imoveis.cod = '$cliente'
GROUP BY clientes.id
```

Alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Perguntas de SQL são mais facilmente respondidas se disser (1) as colunas e tipos das tabelas utilizadas, (2) der exemplos daquilo que devia ser o resultado (output). No caso dos join também é útil saber quais são as chaves estrangeiras (foreign keys), ou seja, quais as colunas de uma tabela que se referem a uma coluna de outra tabela.

Comment: tente COUNT(distinct imoveis.id) AS TOTALIMOVEIS, COUNT(distinct FOTOS.COD) AS TOTALFOTOS , mas como disse o @Edu respostas em SQL passam por conhecer o modelo

Comment: Esta pergunta e esta outra (http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/118412/129) podem ser convertidas numa só?